# Estimating the time until we obtain five-in-a-row?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, probability-theory, approximation

Consider the following random process.  We have a $10\times 10$ grid.  At each time step, we pick a random empty grid cell (selected uniformly at random from among all empty cells) and place a marker in that grid cell.  As soon as we have five contiguous markers in a line (in a row, column, or diagonal), we stop.

I'm given a grid containing some markers in some positions, and I'd like to estimate how long until the process stops if we start from that configuration (i.e., the number of additional time steps until five-in-a-line occurs).  I would be happy with any reasonable metric for that: e.g., the expected time until it stops, or the value $t$ such that there's a probability $0.5$ that the process will stop in $\le t$ time steps.  I'd be happy with an estimate of any such metric.

Is there any efficient algorithm to estimate this metric, given a configuration where some markers have already been placed?  I'm hoping for something faster than random simulation (repeatedly simulating the process and computing an estimate based upon the resulting empirical distribution).

Comment: Random simulation would be pretty fast, how fast an algorithm are you hoping for?

Comment: When doing random simulation, are you keeping counters for the number of ones per row, column and diagonal? That could speed things up.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, that's a good suggestion, I'll try that.  How fast?  The faster, the better.  As far your comment that beating random simulation is going to be tough to beat: fair enough.  I realize that beating random simulation might be awfully unlikely....

Comment: [Percolation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory) seems to be a relevant field here. The phenomena are quite well understood, I wouldn't be surprised if you find a paper about this somewhere.

Comment: This may be too rough for you, and maybe it's just plain naïve, but for what it's worth... (a) it's impossible to get five in a row before adding five markers, and the probability you get five in a row after adding just five is tiny; (b) it's impossible to place sixty-five markers on a 10x10 board without placing five in a row (I think; if not, there is definitely some largest possible number), and the probability of placing 64 without placing five in a row is tiny; therefore, assuming a roughly symmetric cumulative distribution around the mean, I'd guess the average is roughly 35. Thoughts?

Comment: @Patrick87, clever.  I'll mull that over and think about whether I can make any use of it, or whether it too rough.  Thank you for the thought.

Comment: Does "five in a row" mean five _contiguous_ markers in a row?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon, yes, five contiguous markers.  I'll edit the question -- thank you for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: Here's an idea for something I think is doable and will give approximately the right answer. (1) Figure out how to compute for any specific diagonal, row, or column the probability that adding $k$ markers will give you five in a row. (2) Do this for all the rows, columns, and diagonals of your grid and assume they are all independent processes.

Comment: Comment continued. For step (1), you can do it with dynamic programming. For step (2), it's certainly not going to be independent for all configurations—consider the case where there are four 4-in-a-rows, all of which can be completed by the same cell. However, I think for many positions, it will be approximately true. Is this for a programming contest or for some other application?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterShor!  I really like this approach, and I'm trying it out now.  This is for computing the heuristic score function that can be used to build an AI for a two-player game, where the object of the game is to get 5 in a row.

Comment: In a programming contest, it's quite likely you'd get an example where the row, column and diagonal probabilities cannot be treated as all independent. For playing the game, I don't know. But you can estimate how accurate it is by using random simulation.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I coded this up in Mathematica. I started with a $10 \times 10$ matrix initialized to all zeros. I then considered two processes throwing darts in the cells: **(1)**  a cell is chosen uniformly and independently at random from the set of all cells, and **(2)** a cell is chosen uniformly and independently at random from the set of all empty cells. When a  dart hits a cell, the value of that cell is set to $1$. A five-in-a-row can appear on a row, column, the diagonal, or on the antidiagonal.

For both processes, I ran $N = 20000$ simulations. Rounded up to the nearest integer, for process **(1)** we need $65$ dart throws on average to obtain a five-in-a-row. For process **(2)**, the same number was $47$.

This is not exactly what you were asking for, but maybe you can at least compare the numbers you get with mine.